# WP Panorama View

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, panorama-control

I have a Windows Phone 7 application that is in Panorama view. It has a menu (let's say item 0) and 4 other "pages", known as items. The entire panorama is considered one page, so each view are called items.

My question is that how am I able to slide to items 1,2,3 & 4 with the cool sliding transition when a button is pressed in the Menu ? Another question is that how am i able to use silverlight, i installed it but it doesnt appear anywhere.

I used this code 
`panoramaControl.DefaultItem = panoramaControl.Items[1];` 
but it gives a very sucky transition, of just appearing. I tried using storyboard but it doesnt give the sliding transition.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way in code to animate the transition from one PanoramaItem to another. This is because the control is not intended to be used in this way. The DefaultItem property is intended to be used to set the item shown when the page is [re]shown.

Your other question "how am i able to use silverlight, I installed it but it doesnt appear anywhere[?]" doesn't make sense.
If you've got as far as creating a project with a Panorama control then you are using the Silverlight project templates.